# Regular expression to get text between square brackets including disparity?

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I need to find a regular expression for use in C# (JavaScript as well), for get the text inside the either square brackets combination.

I try several ways, but I give up, always my combination have a some errors, somebody can help me please?

```
[text]

[[text]]

[[[tex]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

etc...

Comment: So you just want to remove `[` from the start and `]` from the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matches everything except square brackets: `[^\[\]]+`

This captures anything that is not a square bracket between any number of open (LHS) and close (RHS) square brackets:

`\[+([^\[\]]+)\]+`

Example usage in Javascript:

```
'[[[[[test]]]]'.match(/\[+([^\[\]]+)\]+/)
> ["[[[[[test]]]]", "test"]
```

The regex tester at http://regexpal.com/ is useful for trying out regexes.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use a *regular expression*, the following will work.

```
\[([^[\]]+)\]
```

See [**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/nR4jF9)

Consider replacing those characters instead of trying to match between them.

```
String input  = @"[[[text]]]]]]]]]]]]]";
String output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[[\]]", "");
Console.WriteLine(output); //=> "text"
```

Comment: Why are several good answers being downvoted without comments? this is a good approach, and more readable than the regex answers. +1.

Comment: @hwnd the user asked for regex see the 1st 2 words of question

Comment: There are lot of downvoting trolls in SO nowadays. Beware!

Comment: but there should be some reason as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

This matches everything except square brackets:

`\[([^\[\]]+)\]`

**Output**

text

text

tex

Comment: @A.P. yes, but don't know why people have downvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

This will exclude the square brackets:

```
((?!\[)(?!\]).)+
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/tU2kH3)

[Explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%28%3F%21%5C%5B%29%28%3F%21%5C%5D%29.%29%2B)

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Any problems with it?

Comment: only initial char is selected

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee No, everything would be selected. Did you see the demo? Of course, it has to be a global match though.